# Paths for images and executables in a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path

I have created a java program in eclipse and I am now ready to export it as a jar. My program uses an image file and an executable file. When testing my program in eclipse I referred to these file with a full path, which I obviously cannot do for the jar. Therefore, I changed them like this:

```
public static final String DRIVERLOC = "./resources/IEDriverServer.exe";
//some other code
File file = new File(DRIVERLOC);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

and

```
File pic = new File("./images/Open16.gif");
openButton = new JButton("Select the Text File", createImageIcon(pic.getAbsolutePath()));
```

I put the images and the resources and images directory in the same directory with the jar. Now for some reason when I run the jar the IEDriverServer works fine but the image does not work and the error is that it cannot find the image. I am confused since I cannot seems to tell the difference. I also used "images/Open16.gif" which did not work either. Why would one work but the other does not? What is the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: How do you execute the jar? (From where, what command do you use?)

Comment: Is the images directory external or internal to the jar file?

Comment: An almost-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com//questions/574809/load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar

Comment: I am executing it from the command line using "java -jar filename"

Comment: the image directory is external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this exact same thing with Selenium Drivers.
What you need to do is take the executable file out of the jar and put it some where windows can run it. If you try and open a jar/zip in Windows Explorer and then double click the .exe inside of a jar/zip, windows will extract the file to a temp directory, and then run it. So do the same thing:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream exeInputStream = TestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
        File tempFile = new File("./temp/IEDriverServer.exe");

        OutputStream exeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        IOUtils.copy(exeInputStream, exeOutputStream);

        // ./temp/IEDriverServer.exe will be a usable file now.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Let's say you save the jar and make it run this main function by default.
Running `C:\code\> java -jar TestClass.jar` Will run the jar from the C:\code directory. It will create the executable at C:\code\temp\IEDriverServer.exe

Answer (score 0):

With your path set to "./resources/IEDriverServer.exe" you are referring to a file on the hard drive "." which does not exist.

You need to get the path of your .jar-file. 
You can do this by using

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

This can return multiple values, seperated by semi-colons. The first one should be the folder your jar is in.

You can also use

```
<AnyClass>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

I hope this helps :)

EDIT:

```
// First, retrieve the java.class.path property. It returns the location of all jars /  
// folders (the one that contains your jar and the location of all dependencies)
// In my test it returend a string with several locations split by a semi-colon, so we
// split it and only take the first argument
String jarLocation = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(";")[0];

// Then we want to add that path to your ressource location
public static final String DRIVERLOC = jarLocation + "/resources/IEDriverServer.exe";
//some other code
File file = new File(DRIVERLOC);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

You can read about this **[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).**